# R Studio and R - I don't want to share my variables between scripts

Tags: r, variables, rstudio

I have two scripts open in R Studio file_1 and file_2

If I create variable `x` in file_1 it is immediately available in file_2 and I don't want this to happen.

I tried to use `function` and `local`, but it did not help. I can still access variables from different file.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Open the scripts in different projects. Or if you want to have the scripts open at the same time, rename the variable to `x1`

Comment: If you want both files to be open at the same time in the free RStudio then this is not possible, since ONE R version is running. Your options are: Use the non-free RStudio, do projects like EcologyTom said, or rename the variables.

Comment: @EcologyTom, thank you! Your solution worked!